# How to send message in email body with custom design using bootstrap-4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, smtp, email-attachments, codeigniter-4

I am trying to send message through smtp using CodeIgniter-4 framework. For this purpose, I have designed a card as message body using bootstrap-4 and want to send this message to receiver. I can send this message successfully but the message is not visible as it is designed. Bootstrap-4 class is not working.

**How I want to show receiver:**

[image]

**How it visible to receiver:**
[image]

I think CDN file of Bootstrap-4 isn't available on mail that's why the design isn't working. Could you please help me to send over email with same custom design.

**Let me show you my Code:**

**Email.php file:**

```
namespace Config;
use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Email extends BaseConfig

{

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $fromEmail;

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $fromName;

/**
 * @var string
 */
public $recipients;

/**
 * The "user agent"
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $userAgent = 'CodeIgniter';

/**
 * The mail sending protocol: mail, sendmail, smtp
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $protocol = 'smtp';

/**
 * The server path to Sendmail.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $mailPath = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';

/**
 * SMTP Server Address
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $SMTPHost = 'smtp.office365.com';

/**
 * SMTP Username
 *
 * @var string
 */
// Enter your email id from where you send email
public $SMTPUser = 'exampleMail@gmail.com';


/**
 * SMTP Password
 *
 * @var string
 */
// Enter your email's password
public $SMTPPass = 'myPassword';

/**
 * SMTP Port
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $SMTPPort = 587;

/**
 * SMTP Timeout (in seconds)
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $SMTPTimeout = 60;

/**
 * Enable persistent SMTP connections
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $SMTPKeepAlive = false;

/**
 * SMTP Encryption. Either tls or ssl
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $SMTPCrypto = 'tls';

/**
 * Enable word-wrap
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $wordWrap = true;

/**
 * Character count to wrap at
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $wrapChars = 76;

/**
 * Type of mail, either 'text' or 'html'
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $mailType = 'html';

/**
 * Character set (utf-8, iso-8859-1, etc.)
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $charset = 'UTF-8';

/**
 * Whether to validate the email address
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $validate = false;

/**
 * Email Priority. 1 = highest. 5 = lowest. 3 = normal
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $priority = 3;

/**
 * Newline character. (Use “\r\n” to comply with RFC 822)
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $CRLF = "\r\n";

/**
 * Newline character. (Use “\r\n” to comply with RFC 822)
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $newline = "\r\n";

/**
 * Enable BCC Batch Mode.
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $BCCBatchMode = false;

/**
 * Number of emails in each BCC batch
 *
 * @var integer
 */
public $BCCBatchSize = 200;

/**
 * Enable notify message from server
 *
 * @var boolean
 */
public $DSN = false;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Models\FormModel;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class SendMail extends Controller
{

    function check() { 
      $data['title']="Mail";
      echo view('template/header.php',$data);

        $to = 'exampleMail@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Vehicle Management System';
        $username='Monayem';
        $approver='First Approver';
        $requestId=12;

         $message="<div class='conatiner w-50'>"."<div class='card'>"."<div class='card-header root_bg_color text-white text-center'>"."Vehicle Management System"."</div>"."<div class='card-body'>"."Dear ".$username.", "."<br><br>"."Your vehicle request( ".$requestId." ) is approved by ".$approver."."."Please visit  "."<a href='http://10.12.8.8:8000/vms/public/index.php/Login'>Vehicle Management System</a> to see details."."<br><br>"."Thank You for being with Us"."</div>"."<div class='card-footer root_bg_color'></div>"."</div>"."</div>";

        
        $email = \Config\Services::email();

        $email->setTo($to);
        $email->setFrom('examplemail@gmail.com', 'Vehicle Management System');
        
        $email->setSubject($subject);
        $email->setMessage($message);

        if ($email->send()) 
         {
            echo 'Email successfully sent';
         } 
        else 
         {
            $data = $email->printDebugger(['headers']);
            print_r($data);
        }
   
        echo view('template/footer.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just writing the classes from bootstrap does not make it magically styled.

You must include the css and javascript from a source server say cdnjs.

On another note sending javascript via a message body will be visible as text if the end user does not enable javascript execution.
Sending javascript to the email body is a bad practice.

I would go for just styling rather than bootstrap and include your styles in a `style` tag
There are hundreds of examples creating styled cards and really cool email bodies with just css.
For example this:
[Cool email body](https://codepen.io/Mestika/pen/bEerrv)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue while sending email in my asp.net core MVC project. Then using inline CSS saves me. I think you can go with that.